# How do I run a jQuery function for each container separately?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery function, that allows me to hide/show elements on click.
The hide/show is working fine but I'm trying to run this function for each element separately.

I have tried to do this with an `.each` function but I failed.

How could this be done?

```js
$(".item-closed").on("click", function () {
    $(".item-details").addClass("active");
    $(".item--config").addClass("active");
  });

  $(".item-opened").on("click", function () {
    $(".item-details").removeClass("active");
    $(".item--config").removeClass("active");
  });
```

```css
.item-details{
  color: #09c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-opened{
  display: none;
}


.item-details.active .item-opened{
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-details.active .item-closed{
  display: none;
}

.item--config{
  display: none;
}

.item--config.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="item-details">
  <span class="item-closed">Details anzeigen</span>
  <span class="item-opened">Details ausblenden</span>
</div>

<ul class="item--config">
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>  
<li>option3</li> 
<li>option4</li>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="item-details">
  <span class="item-closed">Details anzeigen</span>
  <span class="item-opened">Details ausblenden</span>
</div>

<ul class="item--config">
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>  
<li>option3</li> 
<li>option4</li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below.

```
$(".item-closed").on("click", function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");   });

  $(".item-opened").on("click", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");   });
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple solution if you don't want to change html then you
>   can identify those by `parent()`.

**Try it:**

```js
$(".item-closed").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".item-details").addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".item--config").addClass("active");
  });

  $(".item-opened").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".item-details").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".item--config").removeClass("active");
  });
```

```css
.item-details{
  color: #09c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-opened{
  display: none;
}


.item-details.active .item-opened{
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-details.active .item-closed{
  display: none;
}

.item--config{
  display: none;
}

.item--config.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="item-details">
  <span class="item-closed">Details anzeigen</span>
  <span class="item-opened">Details ausblenden</span>
</div>

<ul class="item--config">
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>  
<li>option3</li> 
<li>option4</li>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="item-details">
  <span class="item-closed">Details anzeigen</span>
  <span class="item-opened">Details ausblenden</span>
</div>

<ul class="item--config">
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>  
<li>option3</li> 
<li>option4</li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `.parent().parent()` ?

Comment: Becaue: `$(this)` mean current node( ex1: `.item-closed` where you are clicking), parent mean parent of current node (`.item-details`) and again parent mean (`.continer`).
Now you are on container so find out that container's `item--config`. And bind show/hide. Thanks @PeterHein.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the changes and see if it meets ur needs

```js
$(".item-closed").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".item-details").addClass("active");         //changed
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".item--config").addClass("active");         //changed
  });

  $(".item-opened").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".item-details").removeClass("active");         //changed
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".item--config").removeClass("active");         //changed
  });
```

```css
.item-details{
  color: #09c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-opened{
  display: none;
}


.item-details.active .item-opened{
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-details.active .item-closed{
  display: none;
}

.item--config{
  display: none;
}

.item--config.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="item-details">
  <span class="item-closed">Details anzeigen</span>
  <span class="item-opened">Details ausblenden</span>
</div>

<ul class="item--config">
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>  
<li>option3</li> 
<li>option4</li>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="item-details">
  <span class="item-closed">Details anzeigen</span>
  <span class="item-opened">Details ausblenden</span>
</div>

<ul class="item--config">
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>  
<li>option3</li> 
<li>option4</li>  
</ul>
</div>
```